# Symfony 2 - File upload using FormData and ajax, nothing in request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, form-data

I'm trying to upload a file using FormData object and ajax but my file doesn't appear anywhere in the request object in my symfony controller. Here's my HTMl input :

```
<label for="shp-file">Choisir un Shapefile:</label>
<input id ="shp-file" type="file" multiple />
```

My js:

```
$("#shp-file").change(function() {
    var form_data_shp = new FormData();
    form_data_shp.append('file', this.files[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: location.href,
      data: form_data_shp,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
})
```

There's no error in the ajax request, but the object seems to be empty. I have this in my controller:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    return new JsonResponse($request)
}
```

And what I get is an empty Object :

```
Object { attributes: {}, request: {}, query: {}, server: {}, files: {}, cookies: {}, headers: {} }
```

(the file should appear in the `files` key).

Comment: You are trying to serialize an object of class Request, you should not expect to just serialize its variables as you want.

Comment: I think you have to call the DOM with  $ and the the syntax becomes :     form_data_shp.append('file', $(this).files[0]);